# in that passage what longed means?

Tags: vocabulary

> At first I wished to hurry on,for I **longed to console** and sympathize with my loved and sorrowing friends; but when I drew near my native town, I slackened my progress.

here it says longed .I could not encounter with other meaning of "long" without noun.What that means?  and also isn't console meaning game tool ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [**long**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/long) (v):  to want something very much.

For example

> She **longed for** the return of her long-lost father.

In this above sentence the two uses of "long" have two different meanings. "Long-lost" means "to be lost for a *long* time".

> **[console](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/console#dataset-british)** (v): to give comfort and sympathy to someone who is sad or disappointed.

For example:

> She **consoled** her friend after the untimely death of her mother.

Yes, as a noun, "console" can mean a "gaming console" but the pronunciation is different, [with the accent on the first syllable](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/media/english/uk_pron/u/ukc/ukcon/ukconse018.mp3).  The verb "console" [has the accent on the second syllable.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/media/english/uk_pron/u/ukc/ukcon/ukconse019.mp3)

(Click the other links on the Cambridge dictionary page to hear the American pronunciation of both meanings of "console".  Also, I fixed your quote, guessing there was a missing "I" in what you copied.  Please let me know if this is incorrect)